# Add External JAR to Android Project as External SDK like Dropbox sdk or other type of third party sdk

Tags: android

**What I need:**

-One SDK (downloaded JAR) to be import to my project.

-That .JAR having different file that I have to use.

**What I have done so far:**

-Imported the JAR file through external library it doesn't working.

If anybody have the solution please help me to solve.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have provided zero details on what library you are using, what errors you encountered ("doesn't working" is not sufficient) and what you have done to troubleshoot.  Please visit the [help] for information on how to post questions here.

Comment: and you are using ecllipse or android studio??????

Comment: I just have to add a external jar file to my project.suppose I have to integrate the facebook with my project for social login then I have to import the facebook sdk to the project then anyway I have to import the external sdk to the project...thanks.@JimGarrison.

Comment: @AdiTiwari using Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do the following steps:**

-Add your .jar file to **libs** folder

-Right click on that **.jar file** and select **Build Path**

-After that select **Add to Build Path**

-Now it is available with your project
Enjoy.

Hope this will be helpful ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do the following

```
1. go to project->properties
2. Select Java Build Path
3. Select Libraries tab
4. From there you can Add External Jars
```